# Extent Report is not displaying the data correctly, how can I get it right?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, selenium-extent-report

I am using Cucumber for my automation and using Extent Report for generating test reports, After the test is executed, report is generated with report.html name in the target folder. However, when I open the report it does not display the content as it should.

[image]

I have used the dependency the below extent report dependency for cucumber:

```
`<dependency>
<groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>`
```